# Why does Firefox continue to show index.htm when now only index.php exists?

Tags: http, firefox, .htaccess, redirect

I used to have a page on my site called:

http://www.tanguay.info/run/index.htm

I visited it often by going to:

http://www.tanguay.info/run

with my Firefox browser and no other browser.

I have since removed that file "**index.htm**" and replaced it with "**index.php**".

Now when I go to:

http://www.tanguay.info/run

with my Firefox browser it **still shows me** the content of the non-existent index.htm page.

If I **explicitly** go to

http://www.tanguay.info/run/index.htm

it correctly shows me an error, and if I explicitly go to

http://www.tanguay.info/run/index.php

it correctly shows me the PHP page.

I **cleared all my cache** in my Firefox browser but it still shows me the non-existstent index.htm page.

All other browsers and even Firefox on all other machines I've tested show me the correct page (index.php) when they go to

http://www.tanguay.info/run

**Why is this happening and what is the easiest way (e.g. with an htaccess file) for me to force my Firefox browser and potentially all other browsers which had previously been redirected to the index.htm page, to correctly show the index.php page now?**

Comment: Has this Firefox a proxy in its settings? You also could check the network traffic with wireshark/tcpdump to see the request and the replies.

Comment: It's unbelievable, I spent the whole day for exactly the same problem...

Comment: In options|network|connection, the radio button "use system proxy settings" is checked.

Comment: @Novemberland, was this a Firefox issue in your case, or did it happen in other browsers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make sure all requests go to the index.php file by putting this in an .htaccess file inside the /run directory. You'll need to make sure you've enabled mod_rewrite in your Apache configuration.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    ## Turns ModRewrite on
    RewriteEngine On

    ## Stop infinite loops
    RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} 200
    RewriteRule .* - [L]

    ## Allow any existing file to pass through
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
    RewriteRule .* - [L]

    ## Pass any non-existing file to index.php
    RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L,QSA]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: I added an .htaccess file with that content to the tanguay.info/run directory but without change, how can I tell if mod_rewrite is enabled on my web hosting server?, is there an easier way than this: http://www.webune.com/forums/how-to-test-check-if-mod-rewrite-is-enabled-t40.html

Comment: However, I just noticed that what this .htaccess did actually change is now when, with my Firefox browser, I go to tanguay.info/run/index.htm it successfully redirects to index.php, however, when I go to tanguay.info/run, it still shows me the old, non-existent index.htm file

Comment: ok, this actually seemed to work but only AFTER I did a CTRL-refresh in Firefox, thanks, lesson learned: on Apache/PHP web servers, always use index.php